# How to resolve Unmet dependencies with libminiupnpc-dev specificly?

Tags: apt

I have checked other [pages with unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) and applied the solutions but I still receive the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libminiupnpc-dev : Depends: libminiupnpc8 (= 1.6-3ubuntu1) but 1.6-precise2 is to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can some one help with this specific unmet dependency?

Comment: Same issue, I filed a bug here > https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/miniupnpc/+bug/1280060

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get install aptitude && sudo aptitude install libminiupnpc-dev`?

Comment: @ Avinash Raj This worked as a work around. It downgraded the package and unmet dependencies were resolved.

Comment: Because of your's i changed the main question,see http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround that worked was downgrading:

```
sudo aptitude install libminiupnpc-dev
```

I rejected the first option and it automatically searched for another solution. Accepted the next solution which was to downgrade `libminiupnpc8 [1.6-precise2 (now, precise) -> 1.6-3ubuntu1 (precise)]`